# How to release 'Special Powers'?

Tags: ps2, wizardry-forsaken-land

In the game Wizardry Forsaken Land for PS2 I read in PeiPei's Journal about Special Powers and see the option in the item-menu. But if I try it, I get the message: 'You are lacking special powers'. What do I wrong? How can I release special powers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found out, that only some items support this option. Most notably are the class-change-orbs from Kasta's shop on B5.